# Imported Failed: Duplicate Column identifier specified (sqoop)

Tags: sqoop

**Query:**

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdb --username abc --password abc  --query 'SELECT e.*,d.* FROM employee e JOIN department d on e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO  WHERE $CONDITIONS ' --split-by e.DEPTNO  --target-dir /output/result;`

**Error:**

> Imported Failed: Duplicate Column identifier specified (sqoop)

Comment: put `--verbose` in the end of the command and share complete error logs

Comment: check updated answer. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 3):

It is expected behaviour as you are selecting all the columns in your query and both the tables has same column `DEPTNO`.

**select all the columns individually with alias name.**

Modify your query in the similar way:

`--query 'SELECT e.col1 as ecol1, e.col2 as ecol2, e.col3 as ecol3, d.col1 as dcol1, d.col2 as dcol2, c.col3 as dcol3 FROM employee e JOIN department d on e.DEPTNO = d.DEPTNO  WHERE $CONDITIONS'`